# PyQt: Multiple QProcess and output

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qprocess

I have a PyQt window that calls multiple executables as QProcess. How can I list  the outputs of each process after the last one has finished? (something like process_result = ["result1", "result2",..])
Let us say it  looks like this:

```
for i in list_of_processes:
    process = QtCore.QProcess()
    process.start(i)
```

I can read with `process.readyReadStandardOutput()` somehow but it is quite chaotic because processes run parallel. `process.waitForFinished()` does not work because the GUI will freeze.
Also, I checked following page about multithreading: [Multithreading PyQt applications with QThreadPool](https://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/multithreading-pyqt-applications-with-qthreadpool/). Another question is similar but did not help me either: [Pyside: Multiple QProcess output to TextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314571/pyside-multiple-qprocess-output-to-textedit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a class that manages the processes, and that emits a single signal when all the processes finish as you require.

```
import sys

from functools import partial

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class TaskManager(QtCore.QObject):
    resultsChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self.results = []
        self.m_processes = []
        self.number_process_running = 0

    def start_process(self, programs):
        for i, program in enumerate(programs):
            process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
            process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(partial(self.onReadyReadStandardOutput, i))
            process.start(program)
            self.m_processes.append(process)
            self.results.append("")
            self.number_process_running += 1

    def onReadyReadStandardOutput(self, i):
        process = self.sender()
        self.results[i] = process.readAllStandardOutput()
        self.number_process_running -= 1
        if self.number_process_running <= 0:
            self.resultsChanged.emit(self.results)

def on_finished(results):
    print(results)
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    manager = TaskManager()
    manager.start_process(["ls", "ls"])
    manager.resultsChanged.connect(on_finished)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped! Besides, I was wondering if there is any way to queue processes in order to avoid an overload of threads. Let us say my list of programs is extremly long, what could I do?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "overload of processes". Thanks!